# Lost presicion when cast big number varchar2 to number in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm making a load from a flat file, this load include big numbers with 2 decimal digits. This data is stored in a table and the big number is saved in a Number(18,2) field. When the field is read is a varchar2, then I make a to_number convertion, but the last decimal is rounded and I have  information presicion lost

```
select cast ('15999999999999,77' AS number(18,2)) from dual
```

return

```
15999999999999,8
```

These 0.03 are important to me

How can I avoid this lost?

Comment: Are you sure the precision is lost? What about (in SQL*Plus):

    col val format 999999999999999999.99
    select cast ('15999999999999,77' AS number(18,2)) val from dual;

Comment: Right, it's just a display issue with whatever tool you are using. The numeric value of your cast will have the full precision.

Comment: Thanks a lot, both are right. Thanks for getting me out of doubt